# Change div text content one at a time

Tags: jquery, html, text

When running the code, the first text content change doesn't get displayed. It skips onto the next one.

```
$("object").addClass("whip");
if($('object').has('whip'))
{
    $("object").text('whipping'); /* this doesn't seem to get displayed */
}

$("object").addClass("dab");
if($('object').has('dab'))
{
    $("object").text('dabbing');  /* this is the only text displayed and I don't want that */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
has('whip')
```

to

```
is('.whip')
```

Likewise for the `dab` class.

Comment: please have a look at the actual code and see how this doesn't work. http://jsfiddle.net/AXcZx/30/

Comment: That Fiddle bears no resemblance to the code you posted in your question. http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: i just need help with the logic behind a section of the code that I thought would be easy to fix. Can you help me though?

Comment: We're all here to help - but I can't if I can't see what the problem is. Can you make a minimal Fiddle that illustrates just the problem you're having, not with other extraneous code?

Comment: Here is a code section I'm having problem with: http://jsfiddle.net/AXcZx/36/ we can work on it together using this: http://jsfiddle.net/AXcZx/36/#&togetherjs=oqp3sPucci

Comment: Done. http://jsfiddle.net/AXcZx/39/. You had several problems. 1) You were referencing the element "moveme" without the the prefix "#", i.e. it was looking for an element whose tag was called "moveme", not an element with the ID "moveme". 2) You didn't have the JS in the JS panel of JSFiddle - you had it with the HTML. 3) Becuase of 2, you didn't have jQuery enabled in the Fiddle. 4) It's wasteful to continually reference the same element with a selector; consider caching it in a variable.

Answer (score 0):

Both condition should fail, if the second one works, it's just a fluke.
You're checking if `object` "has" `whip`, meaning you're looking for this markup

```
<object>
    <whip></whip>
</object>
```

Using `hasClass()` would be the correct approach here

```
if ( $('object').hasClass('whip') ) {..
```

Of course, you know it does, you just added that class ?

Comment: forgot to mention that 'whip' and 'dab' are styles

Comment: No, they're classes. There's no styles with those names. @adaneo - on a point of pedantry, I always prefer `is()` to `hasClass()` - saves precious bytes in the filesize :)

Comment: When you use `has('whip')`, you're looking for tagNames, neither classes nor styles, hence my point and the markup.

Comment: @Utkanos -  `is()` is shorter to write, but does more work, it can check pretty much any selector as it actually looks up the selector in the DOM and checks it's length. `hasClass()` on the other hand just checks the element(s) `className` property, and does no additional lookups, so it's much faster when looking for a class *(and by much faster, I mean milliseconds, so it's not noticeable anyway)*.

Comment: @adaneo - interesting, I hadn't bothered the two respetive methods up in the source code, but what you say is plausible and makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need this

```
$("object").addClass("whip");
if($('object').hasClass('whip')) {
    $("object").text('whipping');
}

$("object").addClass("dab");
if($('object').hasClass('dab')) {
    $("object").text('dabbing');
}
```